# Flutter - Is there any way to add hyperlink recognition in the textfield like "Whatsapp or google notes etc."

Tags: flutter, chat, textfield

I building a sticky note app but I stuck with the text field in the flutter.
Is there any way to recognise the like rich text field... I would really like help...

I just want when someone put a link in the text field app use network packet to get an image and title description to make a tile.

Just like this... 
[image: a busy cat]

Comment: maybe try this library: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_parsed_text